# Откуда берется отступ?

Tags: вёрстка, css

В [данном примере](http://jsfiddle.net/g5g79/6/) картинка в блоке имеет габариты 100х100. Родительский элемент:

```
<div class="cell"></div>
```

Имеет параметры 100х103. Вопрос прост: откуда взялись эти 3px (черная полоса)? Как убрать этот отступ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line-height: 0;  вместо line-height: 1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n67q9/